# Webcam delay issues

Tags: webcam, internet-connection, upload

I am using a Logitech C120 1.3M Webcam every time I stream it using Skype or some other application there seems to be a 15-20sec delay.

Could this be an issue with the Webcam rather than my connection? My actual download speed is around 1.2mb/s and my upload speed is around 80-90kbps.

If i want this to be a smooth video stream is it worth investing in a new Webcam or should I get an upgrade for my internet connection?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By 15-20sec delay are you referring to:

1. 15-20 seconds before the video starts operating
2. 15-20 seconds between each frame of the video
3. 15-20 seconds delay between what you hear and what you see

Each has a different cause and we need to be clear on what the symptom is.

Comment: @Matt Jenkins I am assume its the broadcast delay for each frame. Its fine on my end but when i view the actual stream or another computer the delay occurs.

Comment: So at the remote end you are getting 1 frame roughly every 15 seconds?  That sounds nasty.  Do you have the ability to test computer-to-computer streaming without using the internet? (two locally connected computers)

Comment: @Matt Jenkins Yes i can do but i'm not sure what software i would use.

Comment: You could have a go with YawCam - [link](http://www.yawcam.com/)

Comment: I've just tested it on another machine it has a PCI-E Network Adapter and there is no lag when i stream using this.

Comment: You mean you plugged the camera into another computer and everything works fine?  That points to a problem with either the computer or the connection between it and the internet.  Is it wireless?

Comment: Yes it is. Both are.

Comment: After further testing there is still about a 5sec delay when i view on my other machine. Do you think its all down to my connection? if i was using an Ethernet cable directly into my router would this solve the problem?

Comment: It's certainly possible.  Another thing to try would be to directly connect the two computers with an ethernet crossover cable - cut out the wireless and router alltogether.